# SUM with Multiple Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a query on SQL Server and have hit a wall on cumulative sum with multiple conditions.

I need to sum all the purchases in a day made by a user, I can do it separately, sum purchases by day(Daily_Total), or sum purchases by user(User_Total), but I run into a wall when I need both conditions met(User_Daily_Total). I tried using GROUP BY, WHERE and HAVING clauses, but it's never the right solution. If anyone can help I'd be so grateful.

Where I tried:

```
select
    UserID, 
    CreateDate, 
    Sale,
    sum(Sale) over (partition by UserID) as User_Total,
    sum(Sale) over (partition by CreateDate) as Daily_Total
from table
```

This is what I need my table to look like, I have everything but the last column, which is where I'm stuck. Help?

Table:

[image]

Comment: 1. Please don't use images. 2. Please show sample data as ideally DDL+DML (because this makes it much easier for people to answer) but if not then as formatted text. 3. Please show desired results as formatted text.

Comment: And whats wrong with `partition by UserID, CreatedDate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last column you need to partition by both columns, as in:

```
select
    UserID, 
    CreateDate, 
    Sale,
    sum(Sale) over (partition by UserID) as User_Total,
    sum(Sale) over (partition by CreateDate) as Daily_Total,
    sum(Sale) over (partition by UserID, CreateDate) as User_Daily_Total
from table
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm super new to SQL and keep overthinking things. I thought I could only use one condition.